# How to fix error with "pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK' " command in Podfile?

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, fbsdk

I try to run "pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'" in my Podfile, but i get this error:

```
[!] Error installing FBSDKMarketingKit
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/bg/v2_zkcfs6m775r4l9wy541vc0000gn/T/d20211001-26597-ngh47r/file.zip https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.38.0.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.10.1 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 1 seconds. 2 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
```

I got this line from facebook events manager, and it says:

> pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

in documentation.

I tried to ping origincache.facebook.com, and didn't get response. I guess this server doesn't work now, but I'm not sure about that.

Has anybody faced this problem before?

If I didn't provide some information, feel free to ask for it, and I'll update question.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is no DNS entry published for that hostname: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3aorigincache.facebook.com

Comment: @CBroe So, do you know what to do in this situation? It will be nice, if there is alternative host to download this package.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't. Maybe the podfile itself needs updating or something, to contain whatever URL they might have replaced this with?

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue (see below) - anyone crack this?

```
Installing FBSDKMarketingKit (4.38.0)

[!] Error installing FBSDKMarketingKit
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/13/f35cz8bs32x35w2kp1mkhckm0000gn/T/d20211213-5118-icg7sb/file.zip https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.38.0.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.10.1 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 1 seconds. 2 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: origincache.facebook.com
```

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I didn't sadly, i changed companies and this was a bit of tech debt that got left behind - curious if you do find a resolution though!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting that error message is that the documentation is outdated and the `Facebook-iOS-SDK` pod is deprecated.

If you need to install the `FBSDKCoreKit` pod, add this to your Podfile:

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 16.3'
```

Make sure the documents you're reading are up-to-date, so you're always using the latest Pods.

I've answered this in a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78099178/5865239.