# Error installing FBSDKMarketingKit while configuring for iOS in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook, facebook-authentication

While configuring flutter_facebook_auth with the iOS and adding the following pods to the Podfile this error occurs:

Pods:

```
pod 'FacebookSDK'
pod 'FacebookSDK/LoginKit'
pod 'FacebookSDK/ShareKit'
pod 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
```

Error:

```
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/lk/0pgk9yz93r748zh3918jdjhm0000gn/T/d20230724-35504-fegrjc/file.zip https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.38.0.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.12.1 cocoapods-downloader/1.6.3'
```

I followed the guidelines from Meta for developers:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/upgrade-guide/

Answer (score 0):

The `'FacebookSDK'` pod has been deprecated, which is why you are receiving that error.

If you need the FBSDKCoreKit, use the following:

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 16.3'
```

If you need the other SDK kits, use the following:

```
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 16.3'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 16.3'
  pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit', '~> 5.15'
```

When in doubt, go to the CocoaPods site, search for the pods and press the "Installation Guide" button on the right, which will tell you exactly what you should add to your Podfile.

Example page: https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKCoreKit

Also, `pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'` is deprecated and you should not be using that.  Share via Messenger is now included in the `FBSDKShareKit` pod.